# Applying multiple custom directives to the same HTML tag in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I assign multiple custom directives to the same tag using AngularJS?

My code is something along the lines of:

```
<div id="fixed" when-scrolled-up="loadMoreUp()" when-scrolled-down="loadMoreDown()">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.id}}</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Here, the loadMoreDown() function is not being triggered. (This is supposed to trigger on the user scrolling down). The following is the definition of the directive:

```
angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolledDown', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];
        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolledDown);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

I have pasted the complete code here : http://plnkr.co/edit/Pn9F2GuJvvkpnXD43km9?p=preview .

This code is supposed implements a reverse infinite scroll. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your example is that you execute the module code twice:

```
// create a new module 'scroll' ...
// and add a directive 'whenScrolledDown'
angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolledDown', ...)

// create a new module 'scroll' ...
// and add a directive 'whenScrolledUp'
angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolledUp', ...)
```

The first directive `whenScrolledDown` is no longer present since the module is cleared. The proper way to add another directive to the same module is:

```
// without the second parameter
angular.module('scroll').directive('whenScrolledUp', ...)

// or
var module = angular.module('scroll', [])

module.directive('whenScrolledDown', ...)
module.directive('whenScrolledUp', ...)
```